# Prime Factorization of very big factorials

Tags: factorial, factoring, prime-factorization

Is there a quick way to prime factorize 50!.

I wrote down all the numbers and then factorized, but that takes way too long.

Comment: I suppose that depends on what you consider "quick" but for each prime less than $50$ just look at the factors of it and how many times the prime appears in each factor individually and add.  For instance, $50!$ has $5$ appearing as a factor a total of $12$ times (once each for $5,10,15,20,25,\dots,45,50$ and an additional time for $25,50$*).  You can repeat this process for each prime less than $50$.

Answer (score 2):

I would list the primes less than $50$ and count how many times each one appears in $50!$

For example $$47,43,41,37,31,29$$ appears only once.
$$23,19,17$$ appears two times each.
$$13$$ appears three times.
$$11$$ appears four times.
$$7$$ appears $8$ times. (49 counts twice ) 
 and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick way to do this. The number of times a prime number $n$ divides $k!$ is given by-
$$N= {\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}}\left\lfloor{k\over n^i}\right\rfloor$$
For example, the power of $2$ in $20!$ will be 
$\left\lfloor{20\over 2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{20\over 4}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{20\over 8}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{20\over 16}\right\rfloor$=10+5+2+1=18.

Hence $2^{18}$ divides $25!$

You would have to do this for all prime numbers till $k!$ though.

*NOTE: The formula doesn't work if n isn't prime*